# Automatic growing number of JS event listeners

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, event-listener

I noticed in the Performance tab of Chrome Dev Tools an always increasing number of JS event listeners in my page.

My page is in vanilla JS, and I didn't do anything for that behavior to happen.

What can be causing it?

[image]

Comment: `What can be causing it?`  Something you did, or maybe a badly designed extension..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to find the elements that get increasingly many event listeners, you could do the following in your dev console:

```js
const findAllChildren = (e, ee = []) => {
    const children = [...e.children];
    ee.push(...children);
    children.forEach((c) => findAllChildren(c, ee));
    return ee;
};
const allElements = [window, ...findAllChildren(document.body)];
const mapToEntry = (e) => [e, Object.values(getEventListeners(e)).flat().length];

const prev = allElements.map(mapToEntry);
```

This will collect all counts of event listeners on the different elements.

Then, when you see the event listeners increased run this script afterwards:

```js
const next = allElements.map(mapToEntry);

const increased = prev.map(([e, count], i) => [e, count, next[i][1]]).filter(([_, prevCount, nextCount], i) => prevCount < nextCount);

console.table(increased.map(([element, prevCount, nextCount]) => ({ element, prevCount, nextCount })));
```

This will print you a table of all elements that got more event listeners attached.

(Chrome) Once, you found the elements, you can inspect in your dev tools pretty easily after clicking in the element inspector on the element and then going to the "Event Listeners" section (sibling of "Styles").

Comment: First and foremost, thank you so much for your patience in writing an answer that thorough, Viktor. However, when I run these two pieces of code on my DevTools, I get "undefined" as answer for both of them. Do you know what can be the reason for that?

Comment: @PedroRabbi I used Chrome to run/create these scripts. If you are using a different browser, some of the above code might not work or might require adjustments.